# Injecting code to Iframe does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I am trying to inject CSS to iframe - problem is it works everywhere except IE and I can’t understand why

thats what I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#the_iframe').load(function(){
        $('#the_iframe').contents().find('head').append('<link href="/css/slider_eri.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    });

});
```

What is wrong here?

Update: For me it seems that IE9 has some issues with load. IE9 will happily accept this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#the_iframe').load(add());
});

function add() {

    var timestamp =  +(new Date());
    $('#the_iframe').contents().find('head').append('<link href="/css/slider_eri.css?'+ timestamp +'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');

};
```

Unfortunately this also breaks all other browsers (including ie7 and 8) so I still have no solution.

Comment: what is not working? i try added some random css at my localhost, and in IE 8 CSS was applied with your code.

Comment: Update: I discovered that it`s not working specifically with IE9!
 In IE 7 and 8 - for my shocking IE runs this script fine.

Comment: You need to read the documentation of `.load`. I don't know why you need `.load` in your case. http://api.jquery.com/load/